# Odd HDD No Response for 5 or 10 secs but Active 100% Transfer 0%

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

I get no response for several seconds from my system. Its not freezing totally I can access the active things.. if i move to a new windows or something after that it freezes.

I am looking at the HDD LED it keeps Blinking in a same pattern while this happens.

In Task Manager Active Time is 100% and Transfer Rate 0% while this happens and then back to normal.

This happens often now. please help. check the attached screenshots of my taskmanager.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Windows 8.1 Pro x64
i3 4gb Ram

Comment: What's the problematic hard drive? and what apps are doing this?

Comment: Hard disk is Seagate

ST1000DM003-1CH162

Its not application specific i guess.. it happens oftenly..

Comment: @JourneymanGeek hello will you be able to help me please ? its very annoying.. i cant complete my works

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i have bought a new hard.. but i still tend to have this sometimes please help. what might be the problem ?

Comment: psu was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSU was the culprit.. i had to buy another HDD but still the problem happened.. and then i have tested using my friends psu with new hdd as the old one was clicking it was working fine. hope it will help someone.